# Hiding a form upon click of the submission button

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
<?php
'<form method="post" action="postnotice.php");>
        <p> <label for="idCode">ID Code (required): </label>
            <input type="text" name="idCode" id="idCode"></p>
        <p> <input type="submit" value="Post Notice"></p>

    </form>'
?>
```

Alright, so that's part of my php form - very simple. For my second form (postnotice.php):

```
<?php
    //Some other code containing the password..etc for the connection to the database.
    $conn = @mysqli_connect($sql_host,$sql_user,$sql_pass,$sql_db);
    if (!$conn) {
         echo "<font color='red'>Database connection failure</font><br>";
    }else{
         //Code to verify my form data/add it to the database.   
    }
?>
```

I was wondering if you guys know of a simple way - I'm still quite new to php - that I could use to perhaps hide the form and replace it with a simple text "Attempting to connect to database" until the form hears back from the database and proceeds to the next page where I have other code to show the result of the query and verification of "idCode" validity. Or even database connection failure. I feel it wrong to leave a user sitting there unsure if his/her button click was successful while it tries to connect to the database, or waits for time out.

Thanks for any ideas in advance,
Luke.

Edit: To clarify what I'm after here was a php solution - without the use of ajax or javascript (I've seen methods using these already online, so I'm trying to look for additional routes)

Comment: The 1990's is calling, it wants it `font` tag back... ;p

Comment: -1 what is the problem exactly? What did you try to solve the problem?

Comment: I have also used CSS too, but I decided to change those ones manually.

Comment: The problem being, while this works fine, is that the user will sit on the initial page for a while without seeing anything, until the next page has discovered whether or not it can connect to the database.

Answer (score 1):

what you need to do is  give form a div and then simply submit the form through ajax and then hide the div and show the message after you get the data from server.

```
<div id = "form_div">


    '<form method="post" id = "form" action="postnotice.php";>
            <p> <label for="idCode">ID Code (required): </label>
                <input type="text" name="idCode" id="idCode"></p>
            <p> <input type="submit" value="Post Notice"></p>

        </form>'
    ?>
    </div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function () {
        $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
          $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'postnotice.php',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
             if(data == 'success'){

            echo "success message";
        //hide the div
       $('#form_div').hide(); //or  $('#form').hide();
              }
            }
          });
          e.preventDefault();
        });
      });
    </script>
```

**postnotice.php**

```
    $idCode  = $_POST['idCode'];

    // then do whatever you want to do, for example if you want to insert it into db 

  if(saveSuccessfulIntoDb){


       echo 'success';

}
```

Comment: I'm actually after a non-ajax solution here. But thank you for this nonetheless, it looks like a decent solution if I was to use ajax

Comment: @LukeBigwood you can't do without ajax or using Jquery

Comment: This was what I was thinking. It's part of a University course on php/ajax - they probably want us to see the benefits of using Ajax by making us go without it first. While I have a site that meets success criteria already I'm trying to make it a little more elegant before final submission date - this being one of the points I'd found that were quite ugly so far as my 'solution' went.

Comment: Thanks for the info, +1 for what looks like a good suggestion however.

Answer (score 0):

try using AJAX. this will allow you to wait for a response from the server and you can choose what you want to do based on the reponse you got.

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.ASP

AJAX with jQuery:
https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Not actually looking to use ajax yet though, we're after a php only solution.